# Error when running (open-mmlab) C:\mmdetection>python setup.py develop - raise RuntimeError(message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

I get the following error in the last stage of the mmdetection install from
https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/master/docs/install.md

when running

```
C:\...\mmdetection\python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing mmdet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mmdet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to mmdet.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to mmdet.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'mmdet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mmdet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
C:\...\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:237: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))

building 'mmdet.ops.utils.compiling_info' extension
Emitting ninja build file C:\...\mmdetection\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build.ninja...
Compiling objects...
Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)

FAILED: C:/.../mmdetection/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/mmdet/ops/utils/src/compiling_info.obj
cl /showIncludes /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD /MD /wd4819 /EHsc -DWITH_CUDA -IC:\torch\include -

CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1400, in _run_ninja_build
    check=True)
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 300, in <module>
    zip_safe=False)
  File "C:...\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in 
  File "C:\...\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1140, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects 
    ..............
    error_prefix='Error compiling objects for extension')
  File "C:\...\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1413, in _run_ninja_build

raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what could be the cause of this error message ?

I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Use cudatoolkit==10.0 not 10.2 so that pytorch 1.4 is used instead of pytorch 1.5. This fixes the issue. However if using mmdetection v2.0.0 it seems that pytorch 1.5 with cudatoolkit==10.2 works fine.

Comment: see below experiment by switching github tag to v2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In github https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/v2.0.0/docs/install.md

by following the instructions, but this time switching github tag to v2.0.0 and cloning it

typing in this

```
pip install -v -e .
```

gives the following.  :-

```
#sha256=a37ee82f1b8ed4b4645619c504311e71ce845b78f40055e78d71add5fab7da82 (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/c2/e9cf54ae5b1102020ef895866a67cb2e1aef72f16dd1fde5b5fb1495ad9c/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=dcb8da8c5ebaa6360c8555547a4c7beb6cd983dd95ba895bb78b86cc8cf3de2b (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/)
  ... lots more link skipping
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp38-cp38-win32: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/d6/516883f8d2f255c41d8c560ef70c91085f2ceac7b70b7afe41432bd8adbb/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp38-cp38-win32.whl#sha256=1ab92d807427641ec45d28d5907426aa06b4ffd19c5b794729c74d91cd95090e (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp38-cp38-win_amd64: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/9e/56d8b98652ecac8c8f9e59b7f00d5d99a9fa86661adcf324b8dc73351a6b/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl#sha256=e2206bb8c17c0f212f1f356d82d72dd090ff4651994034416da9bf0c29732825 (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/)
Given no hashes to check 18 links for project 'opencv-python': discarding no candidates
Using version 4.2.0.34 (newest of versions: bunch of versions....)
Collecting opencv-python>=3
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-y8apfmt3
  Looking up "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/17/bad54f67bbe27d88ba520c3f59315e95b4e254cd28767c20accacb0597d8/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 1902095
  Ignoring unknown cache-control directive: immutable
  Freshness lifeOneWorlde from max-age: 365000000
  The response is "fresh", returning cached response
  365000000 > 1902095
  Using cached opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (33.0 MB)
  Added opencv-python>=3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/17/bad54f67bbe27d88ba520c3f59315e95b4e254cd28767c20accacb0597d8/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=d8a55585631f9c9eca4b1a996e9732ae023169cf2f46f69e4518d67d96198226 (from mmcv>=0.5.1->mmdet==2.0.0+unknown) to build tracker 'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-6eq3f7le'
  Removed opencv-python>=3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/17/bad54f67bbe27d88ba520c3f59315e95b4e254cd28767c20accacb0597d8/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=d8a55585631f9c9eca4b1a996e9732ae023169cf2f46f69e4518d67d96198226 (from mmcv>=0.5.1->mmdet==2.0.0+unknown) from build tracker 'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-6eq3f7le'
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.3->mmdet==2.0.0+unknown) (0.18.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: mmcv
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-93yp2cnh
  Building wheel for mmcv (setup.py) ...   Destination directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-93yp2cnh
  Running command 'C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-voimjxde\\mmcv\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
amd64-3.7\mmcv\video\optflow_warp
  copying mmcv\video\optflow_warp\flow_warp_module.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mmcv\video\optflow_warp
....etc.

  running build_ext
  skipping './mmcv/video/optflow_warp\flow_warp_module.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'mmcv._ext' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmcv
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmcv\video
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmcv\video\optflow_warp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tp./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.obj
  flow_warp.cpp
  ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp(37): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
  ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp(38): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
  ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp(59): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
  ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.cpp(60): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /EHsc /Tp./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\flow_warp_module.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\flow_warp_module.obj
  flow_warp_module.cpp
  c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__ext build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\flow_warp_module.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mmcv\_ext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\_ext.cp37-win_amd64.lib
  flow_warp_module.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__ext' specified multiple OneWorldes; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\_ext.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\./mmcv/video/optflow_warp\_ext.cp37-win_amd64.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\mmcv
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\mmcv\arraymisc
  copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mmcv\arraymisc\quantization.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\mmcv\arraymisc
...
... bunch of copying and creating...
...
  running install_egg_info
  Copying mmcv.egg-info to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\mmcv-0.5.8-py3.7.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\wheel\pep425tags.py:82: RunOneWorldeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
    warn=(impl == 'cp')):
  C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\wheel\pep425tags.py:87: RunOneWorldeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
    sys.version_info < (3, 8))) \
  creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\mmcv-0.5.8.dist-info\WHEEL
  creating 'C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-93yp2cnh\mmcv-0.5.8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it
  adding 'mmcv/__init__.py'
  adding 'mmcv/_ext.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
  adding 'mmcv/version.py'
  adding 'mmcv/arraymisc/__init__.py'
  adding 'mmcv/arraymisc/quantization.py'
  adding 'mmcv/cnn/__init__.py'
etc...
  adding 'mmcv/visualization/optflow.py'
  adding 'mmcv-0.5.8.dist-info/METADATA'
  adding 'mmcv-0.5.8.dist-info/WHEEL'
  adding 'mmcv-0.5.8.dist-info/top_level.txt'
  adding 'mmcv-0.5.8.dist-info/RECORD'
  removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
done
  Created wheel for mmcv: filename=mmcv-0.5.8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=184354 sha256=023fa1fdb01a9fbf7d833975737bc93003c5f1c813ce8c4ae27340b19ddb9cc3
  Stored in directory: c:\users\OneWorld\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\cc\7c\4c\a2cc81d990c63b3d157ab3c6e2cc4b5b298c0a4a13e6a46e38
Successfully built mmcv
Installing collected packages: addict, pyyaml, yapf, opencv-python, mmcv, Pillow, terminaltables, mmdet
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-n1vstot6

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-qqv40s97

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-yk9n5qrl

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-dmbql_3c

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-6vlnr7x0

  Attempting uninstall: Pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 7.1.2
    Uninstalling Pillow-7.1.2:
      Created temporary directory: c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\~il
      Removing file or directory c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pil\
      Created temporary directory: c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\~illow-7.1.2.dist-info
      Removing file or directory c:\users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pillow-7.1.2.dist-info\
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-7.1.2
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-thrgvqkj

  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpacked-wheel-9orxl8mp

  Running setup.py develop for mmdet
    Running command 'C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing mmdet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to mmdet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to mmdet.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to mmdet.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'mmdet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'mmdet.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'mmdet.ops.utils.compiling_info' extension
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet\ops
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet\ops\utils
    creating C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet\ops\utils\src
    Emitting ninja build file C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build.ninja...
    Compiling objects...
    Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
    C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:237: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))
    [1/1] cl /showIncludes /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD /MD /wd4819 /EHsc -DWITH_CUDA -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include" -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" -c C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\mmdet\ops\utils\src\compiling_info.cpp /FoC:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet\ops\utils\src/compiling_info.obj -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=compiling_info -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 /std:c++14
    FAILED: C:/Users/OneWorld/Documents/DeepLearning/VideoObjectSegmentation/mmdetection-2.0.0/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/mmdet/ops/utils/src/compiling_info.obj
    cl /showIncludes /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD /MD /wd4819 /EHsc -DWITH_CUDA -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include" -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include -IC:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" -c C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\mmdet\ops\utils\src\compiling_info.cpp /FoC:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\mmdet\ops\utils\src/compiling_info.obj -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=compiling_info -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 /std:c++14
    CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1400, in _run_ninja_build
        check=True)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\Documents\DeepLearning\VideoObjectSegmentation\mmdetection-2.0.0\setup.py", line 300, in <module>
        zip_safe=False)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 38, in run
        self.install_for_development()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 140, in install_for_development
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 87, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 580, in build_extensions
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
        _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 208, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 562, in win_wrap_ninja_compile
        with_cuda=with_cuda)
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1140, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
        error_prefix='Error compiling objects for extension')
      File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1413, in _run_ninja_build
        raise RunOneWorldeError(message)
    RunOneWorldeError: Error compiling objects for extension
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in C:\Users\OneWorld\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-voimjxde\mmcv
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-6eq3f7le'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 404, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 71, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 802, in install
    unpacked_source_directory=self.unpacked_source_directory,
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\editable_legacy.py", line 51, in install_editable
    cwd=unpacked_source_directory,
  File "C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\OneWorld\anaconda3\envs\open-mmlab2\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\OneWorld\\Documents\\DeepLearning\\VideoObjectSegmentation\\mmdetection-2.0.0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

Seems like error messages, anything wrong with this?  How can I check that HTC detection is working ?

This is using Windows 10